# ASP.Net: DataTable not passed by reference to function?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

I'm trying to write an application that has to juggle multiple DataTables and query the SQL server multiple times for each of them. I ended up creating this function:

```
        protected void QueryExec(string Query, DataTable Table, bool append = false) {
        if (!append)
            Table = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection Connector = new SqlConnection(/*connection data here*/);

        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connector);
        Connector.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        Adapter.Fill(Table);
        Connector.Close();
    }
```

To avoid writing the same stuff every time. However, now that I am trying to actually run the code, I run into a problem. If I execute the following function during the page load/button press:

```
        protected void OrderListGrab() {

        var Query = "query";
        QueryExec(Query, OrderList);

        MainGridView.AllowPaging = true;
        MainGridView.DataSource = OrderList;
        MainGridView.DataBind();
        MainGridView.Font.Size = 9;
    }
```

I end up with an empty datatable. If however, I substitute this line:

```
        QueryExec(Query, OrderList);
```

With this:

```
        SqlConnection Connector = new SqlConnection(/*connection data here*/);

        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connector);
        Connector.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        Adapter.Fill(OrderList);
        Connector.Close();
```

Then everything works just fine, the data is in my DataTable (can see it being put into DataGridView and export it to Excel properly).

I am pretty new to any web programming, so this behaviour is very puzzling to me. Does anybody know what is wrong with this code?

Comment: You can use `ref` if you need it but i would return this `DataTable` from the method instead. So rename it to `GetDataTable` and change `void` to `DataTable`. But you should not pass query-strings to a method, that will be a sql-injection vulnerability. Instead provide meaningful methods for every task like `GetUsers` and use sql-parameters. Pass only the values to the methods.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That way works indeed, thank you :) And for the vulnerability tip as well, I didn't consider the implications of having a method like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because of the below code block where you are creating a new datatable. Your method signature `QueryExec(string Query, DataTable Table, bool append = false)` and you are calling `QueryExec(Query, OrderList)`. So the variable `append = false` and thus the below code block ends up creating a new DataTable instance.

```
    if (!append)
        Table = new DataTable();
```

Comment: Just checked and yes, that was it. I didn't expect it to 'lose track' of the table like this after such operation, but it does. Substituting with `Table.Clear()` makes the issues go away and still achieves what I wanted to do in the first place (make sure I can either fill the DataTable with completely new data or add to it easily.  
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method must return a DataTable since in your way you are not sending a reference to your DataTable

```
 protected DataTable QueryExec(string Query,DataTable Table, bool append = false) {
    if (!append)
        Table = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection Connector = new SqlConnection(/*connection data here*/);

    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connector);
    Connector.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
    Adapter.Fill(Table);
    Connector.Close();
    return Table;
}
```

You can also use `ref` if you want to pass a pointer to your object:

```
 protected void QueryExec(string Query,ref DataTable Table, bool append = false) {
    if (!append)
        Table = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection Connector = new SqlConnection(/*connection data here*/);

    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connector);
    Connector.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
    Adapter.Fill(Table);
    Connector.Close();
}
```